# I there any way to capture KEYCODE_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN event in background?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, key-events

I am trying to create an application which need to capture event when `KEYCODE_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN` button pressed.Is there any way to achieve this via BroadcastReciever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want to do.
Because, KEYCODE_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN is quiet new(from level 18), I couldn't find a device which uses KEYCODE_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN on hardware/software key.

But, if softkeyboard/hardware_device send a keyEvent throw inputconnection.sendKeyEvent(keyEvent), this one will be work.

```
    public class myClass implements OnKeyListener {
        .....;

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyCode == KeyEvents.KEYCODE_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN) {
                   .....
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
   }
```

I really not sure hardware_button/softkey will send keyEvent throw inputConnection(normally they do), but if they do, you can get keyEvent throw onKeyDown(...);

I hope this one help you. Thanx.